# Adds JSON String in <template> element, in Svelte REPL

Tags: javascript, json, svelte

I need one hartcoded JSON string in a template, like thes:

```
<template id="Todo">
  [{
  "todo":"Learn Svelte",
  "done":false
  },{
  "todo":"Two",
  "done":false
  },{
  "todo":"Three",
  "done":false
  }]
</template>
```

But then error is:

[image]

That is normal JavaScript, works in other REPLs like JSFidlle.

`JSON.parse(document.getElementById("Todo").innerHTML)`

What to do?

Comment: I think you are trying to use the Svelte Repl for something that it was not intended to be used for. The Svelte Repl is specific to Svelte, a web framework that has its own component system. If <template> is no Svelte component, you won't be happy using that Repl.

Comment: Sorry, yes, then I use it wrong. I thought Svelte was HTML5 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Svelte will interpret `{...}` as places to [interpolate JavaScript expressions](https://svelte.dev/docs#Text_expressions). A possible approach is to actually call `JSON.stringify` to create the JSON:

```
<template id="Todo">
  {JSON.stringify(`
    [{
      "todo":"Learn Svelte",
      "done":false
    },{
     "todo":"Two",
     "done":false
    },{
     "todo":"Three",
    "done":false
    }]
  `)}
</template>
```

Comment: But then its not a <template>; They should be not parsed. I have many HTML template with string that my program self will parse as String Literal. Is there other HTML tag that Svelte not parsed will?

Comment: Why is it not a template? *"They should be not parsed."* But that's how Svelte components work.

Comment: A <template> tag is parsed, it just isn't displayed initially. Also, Svelte will parse and compile the whole component code at build time, long before it appears in the browser, there is no "don't parse this part"-logic. Use the provided answer above or use `{@html ...}` which you can pass a template literal string to with the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better/simpler solutions but here's one

Add the json language to your preprocess config

```js
preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
    sourceMap: !production,
    /** Add a custom language preprocessor */
    json({ content, filename, attributes }) {
        // html encode the brackets
        content = content.replace(/\}/g, "&#125;");
        content = content.replace(/\{/g, "&#123;");
        return { code: `<pre>${content}</pre>` };
    },
}),
```

Then set the `lang` attribute of the template to `json`

```
<template lang="json">
    [{
        "todo":"Learn Svelte",
        "done":false
    },{
        "todo":"Two",
        "done":false
    },{
        "todo":"Three",
        "done":false
    }]
</template>
```

Comment: I am using the online Svelte REPL (with vanilla JavaScript and HTML in it). The REPL is faster (way faster) then CodePen. Thats why I want to use it.